# How to use cross apply with Sql Kata

Tags: sql, sqlkata

I am dont know to construct a query with  Cross Apply and SqlKata. I was searching the net and I find out that cross apply was not supported by SqlKata. Is there any other way to achieve my requirements.

```
var query = new Query("Test as t")

cross apply
(select top 1 t2.TestID from Test as t2  where t1.LegID = t2.LegID order by t2.Sequence desc)
```

This is the sql query

```
select * from Test1 t1
cross apply
(select top 1 s.OperationalStopID
    from Test2 t2
    where t2.LegID = t1.LegID
    order by t2.SequenceNumber desc) t3
```

Comment: _"I am strugaling to construct a query"_ Can you edit the Question and add the details `How exactly` you are struggling, like getting `Error messages`, or just something that you `observed` that was different from what you had `expected` exactly?

Comment: Can you show the SQL (as in `non-sqlkata`) equivalent  of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I submited the query, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Join` method and pass "CROSS APPLY" or whatever method you like in the last parameter

check this example on [SqlKata Playground](https://sqlkata.com/playground?code=var%20another%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22Test2%20as%20t2%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.WhereColumns(%22t2.LegID%22%2C%20%22%3D%22%2C%20%22t1.LegID%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Select(%22s.OperationalStopID%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.OrderByDesc(%22t2.SequenceNumber%22)%0A%20%20%20%20.Limit(1)%3B%0Avar%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22Test1%20as%20t1%22).Join(another.As(%22t3%22)%2C%20j%20%3D%3E%20j%2C%20%22CROSS%20APPLY%22)%3B)

```cs
var another = new Query("Test2 as t2")
    .WhereColumns("t2.LegID", "=", "t1.LegID")
    .Select("s.OperationalStopID")
    .OrderByDesc("t2.SequenceNumber")
    .Limit(1);
    

var query = new Query("Test1 as t1").Join(another.As("t3"), j => j, "CROSS APPLY"); // <---
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `sqlkata`, but you can rewrite your SQL query to an inner join, like:

```sql
select DISTINCT
  t1.I,
  t1.LegID,
  x.OperationalStopID
from test1 t1
inner join (select LegID, MAX(OperationalStopID) as OperationalStopID
            from test2
            group by LegID) x on x.LegID = t1.LegID
```

I hope you are able to convert this SQL query to `sqlkata` syntax ?

This query is tested here: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/A59K4Cdp)

P.S.: oops, the `DISTINCT` should not have been in there anymore, please remove it.